# jQuery mobile get without page redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following:

```
<div data-role='popup' id='popupSchedule' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all'>
    <form id='schedule'>
        <div style='padding:10px 20px;'>
            <div data-role='fieldcontain'>
                <label for='masterOn'>Activate:</label>
                <input type='time' name='masterOn' id='masterOn' value='' data-mini='true' data-theme='a'>
                <label for='masterOff'>Deactivate:</label>
                <input type='time' name='masterOff' id='masteroff' value='' data-mini='true' data-theme='a'>
                <input type='submit' id='setSchedule' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check' value='Confirm'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

that is a popup in jQuery...
What I want to do is a `GET` with the elements (masterOn, masterOff ) values when the user clicks the submit button, like:

```
"$('#schedule').submit(function(event) { "
    "$.get('/cmd', masterOn value ..... masterOff value ...);

"});"
```

Then close the popup without page redirection (because I have a multi-page implementation and I need it to not redirect).

Comment: Have you tried $("#popupSchedule").popup("close");

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#schedule').submit(function(event) { 
  $.get("/cmd", { masterOn : $("#masterOn").val(), masterOff : $("#masterOff").val() } )
   .done(function( data ) {
     // do your stuff with data
   })
   .fail(function() {
     // do your stuff if get fails
   });
   return false; // this is what you need to do to prevent page redirection
});
```

Comment: thank you :)
Is there any  way to generalize this instead of doing one function per form ? That is... whatever is the name of the form, on submit, it would send the values of the form fields, without me needing to specify them individually for each form